# Typo3 9.5: How to render content of certain colPos of certain Page within Fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I've created an extra page with an extra 5 Column BackendLayout for my Footer I want to display within my entire page. So I made a Partial of my Footer which I include into my Layout/Templates. Works fine so far.

My footer page has the pageID 84.
Is there a way to tell my Fluid template to display each col of my footer page with its ID 84?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this with the following:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{pageUid: '84', colPos: '0'}" />
```

Comment: You should mention that `lib.dynamicContent` is not part of the TYPO3 core, but a custom rendering helper that could easily be added to your TypoScript setup. It's [part of the 
 bootstrap_package](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/DynamicContent.typoscript), for example.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry not mentioning this. I'm using the sitepackage by Benjamin Kott as a base for my frontend > https://sitepackagebuilder.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another way of managing such kind of footer would be to enhance the BE-layout of your (web-)root page with five columns for the footer (you might use the IDs 91 to 95).
Then you can render those columns like any other content column. You only add a `slide` so the content is inherited to all other pages.

```
footerColumn1 < styles.content.get
footerColumn1.select.where = colPos=91
footerColumn1.slide = -1

footerColumn2 < .footerColumn1
footerColumn2.select.where = colPos=92

:
```

Subpages don't need to contain these columns, except you want to interact with the inheritance and modify the footer for special pages.